# How to optimize UITableViewCell rendering, when using CGContextDrawLinearGradient

Tags: iphone, performance, ios, uitableview, core-graphics

I have a UITableView where I am trying to get the best possible scrolling performance.

The cell does not contain any subviews, all is done in the drawRect method.

Each cell has a white line at the top, a grey line at the bottom and a linear gradient between top and bottom. On top of this background is some text and an image.

I can see from using instruments that the main portion (>50%) of the runtime when scrolling comes from the drawing of the linear gradient. Actually almost all of that comes from the call to CGContextDrawLinearGradient.

Is there a good way to optimize this? I am thinking, either cache the linear gradient some way, or maybe draw it in another way... Maybe draw a one pixel wide and then stretch it?

Here is some of my code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect  
{  
  [self drawCellBackground:rect];  
  [self drawSeparator:rect];  
  ....
}

- (void)drawCellBackground:(CGRect)rect
{
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  CGColorRef notQuiteWhiteColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 
                                             blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
  CGColorRef lightGrayColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:235.0/255.0 green:235.0/255.0 
                                             blue:235.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

  drawLinearGradient(context, rect, notQuiteWhiteColor, lightGrayColor);
}
```

From a separate .c file:

```
void drawLinearGradient(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, CGColorRef startColor, CGColorRef  endColor)
{
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  CGFloat locations[] = { 0.0, 1.0 };

  NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)startColor, (id)endColor, nil];

  CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, 
                                                  (CFArrayRef) colors, locations);

  CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
  CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

  CGContextSaveGState(context);
  CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
  CGContextClip(context);
  CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
  CGContextRestoreGState(context);

  CGGradientRelease(gradient);
  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you absolutely want to stick to using drawRect: (which I believe gives better performance than separate views on older devices), why not prerender your gradient into a CGImage or UIImage, then use that to draw in -drawRect: ?

Also, you can create your gradient ahead of time:

```
static CGGradientRef GetCellBackgroundGradient()
{
    static CGGradientRef gradient = NULL ;
    if ( !gradient )
    {
        gradient = // create your CGGradientRef here
    }

    return gradient;
}
```

For high performance code you want to preallocate as many things (memory/objects) as possible.

Comment: also, I don't think you need to CGContextClip() unless your gradient is using the fill before/fill after options, right?

Comment: I think this may be the way to go. It is a fairly simple excercise. I'll update the question with my findings.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this. I am caching the gradient as a UIImage and then just do a drawInRect on that.

Comment: Yes, caching the gradient as a rasterized UIImage will be a lot more effective than caching the CGGradientRef. Creating the CGGradientRef is almost free (compared to drawing the gradient).

Answer (score 2):

Are you reusing table view cells properly?  If so, in this case I think you will be better off using subviews on your table view instead of doing all drawing in `drawRect:`.  By using subviews, and assuming the gradient is the same for all cells, the gradient would only have to be drawn once per reusable cell.  When it gets recycled with new content, only the text and image views will need to be updated instead of having to draw the gradient all over again.

Comment: Yes. I reuse cells. You might right on the subviews part. I guess I am only able to tell by testing. Is it possible to combine the two methods?

Comment: Sure -- for example you could create a custom UIView subclass that draws the image and text into a single view, and put that as a subview of the cell. Another idea is to draw the gradient once into an image and simple construct a normal UITableViewCell by setting the `backgroundView` to a UIImageView with the gradient, and add the text and image to the `contentView`.